Do Bloc State Variables Persist when using Register Factory?
I'm using dependency injection with Bloc . When I initialize my Bloc I call:
getIt.registerFactory<RemoteGroceryItemsBloc>(
      () => RemoteGroceryItemsBloc(getIt(),getIt())); 

I basically :

call a service to pull down a list of data (getIt()..add(event #1).

Call another service to save a new item to that list I just downloaded (getIt()..add(event #2).

Then append the list in #1 with the new item in #2

Problem is I need to persist the list in step #1 so I can append it in step #2

So I persist the list in my state class and pass it to my use case for step #2 (I do this because I do not want appending logic in the UI - just want to pass the new appended list back to the UI)


My question is, if I'm using factory class (new instance created on every call) for Bloc then how will second call ( ( getIt()..add(event #2)) be able to access original list in Step #1. Am I missing something?

Yep, If using registerFactory class state variables will not persist. I switch my Bloc declaration to a registerSingleton and then of course my state variable persisted. Not sure if that is bad practice but also not sure a way around it.
